# What is RTAG7 hash

Tags: juniper, network-core, asics

I am trying to read about RTAG7 hashing in ASICs. I am unable to find good literature on it. Can someone please explain what is the RTAG7 hash?

Comment: Find the ASIC's documentation. I'd offer an answer from Broadcom, but the document is covered by an NDA. *RTAG7* is simply register designation; the actual function (math) is vendor specific.

Comment: http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/force10-s4048-on/S4048_ON_9.9.0.0_Config_Pub-v1/RTAG7?guid=GUID-9BDA04B4-E966-43C7-A8CF-F01E7CE600F4&lang=en-us  That's the only public reference I can find.

Comment: Where can I find the ASIC documentation?

Comment: From the manufacturer. Unless you are a direct customer, expect either "no" or no answer at all.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an enhanced hashing. This hashing technique takes into account multiple packet parameters like SRC IP , DST IP, SRC Mac etc instead of only SRC Mac or SRC IP etc